# Comma before the word "as"

Tags: punctuation, commas

This is my sentence:

> The A & P’s regular customers are depicted as "scared little pigs in a chute."  Daily,  they live the same monotonous existence.

Microsoft word insists that there should be a comma after "depicted".  I don't think it makes sense.  What say you?

Comment: Discussed in many previous threads. Look up "comma before quote" in the search facility.

Comment: The suggestion here seems to be a comma before the word before the quote.

Comment: It seems to me that the addition of the comma in that location would make the sentence ungrammatical.

Comment: @nxx definitely not a duplicate, because they are all about putting the comma after *as*, while this question is about putting it after *depicted*.

Comment: Ah you are quite right. It is not about the quote.

Answer (score 1):

You're right. There's absolutely no need for a comma after 'depicted'. In fact, a comma would only confuse the reader. (My version of MS Word, incidentally, doesn't suggest a comma.)

Comment: +1. In general when you think about the subtleties of grammar it's quite impressive that word processors do as well as they do, but unsurprising that they often get things wrong, sometimes strongly so.